# Dynamic load components from list of id

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 100+ components but not all the components will use in page.
For example, user will choose list of components ids (`components_ids = [7, 50, 22]`).
When visit the page, I will use `components_ids` to load the components which its id equals to 7 or 50 or 22.

I found that all the components can be load in page and use `:is` to dynamic use the component, but load 100+ components into page is a little be waste to memory.

How could I load just the components used by user selected?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <component v-for="component in myComponents" :is="component"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      component_ids: ['select', 'input', 'modal']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myComponents() {
      return this.component_ids.map(id => () => import(`@/components/${id}.vue`));
    }
  }
}
</html>
```

Obviously I used words instead of numeric IDs like you did, but this is just a matter of mapping IDs to component paths

When you look at the double lambda `id => () => import('@/components/${id}.vue')` you may be a little worried.

The point here is that we are mapping an array of strings to an array of functions that return a component.

`<component :is="() => import('@/components/hello.vue)"` would work

`:is="import('@/components/hello.vue')"` wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  
I have another question coming out. The id in myComponents will be uncertain, which means the vue app needs to load all the components file first. Or did I misunderstanding how vue works.

Comment: Is the double lambda part only load the dynamic components that in the `component_ids` or it loads all the components and then import it to vue app?

Comment: It loads only component_ids